# Issue with QDAP Top Positive words

Tags: r, qdap

I am using QDAP polarity function for my effort.
It works great !!!

I face an issue calculating top positive words 
so here is what I did so far

```
(pol_All_Rev_aftersplit <- with(All_Review_Mod_Split_df, polarity(rm_stopwords(review_text), polarity.frame = POLENV)))

pos_words_rating <- data.frame(with(counts(pol_All_Rev_aftersplit), wfm(pos.words)))
pos_words_rating <- pos_words_rating[order(pos_words_rating$all, decreasing = TRUE), , drop= FALSE] ## to sort the df
```

I have seen that

```
counts(pol_All_Rev_aftersplit) #is a data frame
```

so far so good ....

Issue:

```
pos_words_rating
```

dataframe  shows results like

```
7   **cworks    65**
8   accurate    59
12  right   43
13  works   39
16  nice    28
17  **clike 26**
18  **cwork 25**
```

What are the 'c' words these are certainly not present in the

```
counts(pol_All_Rev_aftersplit)
```

dataframe or in any of the review text. Unfortunately I will not be able to post the review comments(actual data).

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose the problem without a reproducible example (this is usually expected on stackoverflow).  `qdap` comes with a number of built in data sets that could possible be used to reproduce the problem.  I suspect the problem arises in that `qdap` stores the positive and negative words in a dataframe as a column, however, each cell is actually a vector that may have multiple elements.  You can change this by something like: `sapply(counts(m)$pos.words,  paste, collapse=" ")` for positive and negative word columns.

Comment: Actually I realized that and solved my requirement. Here is what I did. Basically i converted the column to string vector before applying wfm()                                                                       `ww_pos <- sapply(pol_All_Rev_aftersplit_df$pos.words, function(x) toString(x))
pos_words_rating <- data.frame(wfm(ww_pos))`

Comment: Perhaps you could answer your own question with reproducible data for future searchers?